# Is there a way to use PreferenceScreen for any arbitrary activity inside of an Android app?

Tags: android

In Android, we have the SharedPreferences / PreferenceScreen framework that let's us build application-wide (application global) settings/preferences.  We use a key to refer to the elements and we can use the built-in framework to adjust values and ranges.

What about when we want to add settings to any arbitrary screen (like a per-record activity)?

Consider a todo list sample app.  A todo list (object) can have settings such as the name of the todo list and the color of the background.  One approach is to build an "edit todo list" screen and build it like any other fragment/activity/view.  This works.

But there's a lot of boilerplate.

It would be convenient to use a PreferenceScreen for that.  Can that be done? (we would need to save the data to the application database)

A corollary to what I'm asking for specifically is if there is an idiomatic way to do per-record settings available in android apps that avoids me having to write a lot or all of the usual form/validation/logic code?